# How to reuse same partitioning across multiple logical-offset windows in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `df` with the below schema (Spark 2.4)

```py
root
 |-- segId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- val1: double (nullable = true)
```

where

- `segId` is a segment (think of it as a unique identifier)
- `time` is the timestamp when some measurement was taken
- `val1` is the value of the measurement

I need to compute mean (or some custom aggregation) of `val1` over several `rangeBetween`s. For example, I want to compute mean over last 1 minute, 2 minutes, ..., 100 minutes for each segment.

I do not want to create a 100 windows (where it is paritioned and sorted 100 times). I want to create one physical window (partition by `segId` and order by `time` once), and then use a `rangeBetween` for last n minutes (logical offset over the previously partitioned set).

Code example for just computing last 1, 2 and 3 minutes:

```py
win_physical = Window.partitionBy("segId").orderBy(F.col("time").cast("long"))

df = (
    df.repartition("segId")
    .orderBy(F.col("time").cast("long"))
    .withColumn("mean1Mins", F.mean("val1").over(win_physical.rangeBetween( -(60-1), 0)))
    .withColumn(
        "mean2Mins", F.mean("val2").over(win_physical.rangeBetween(-(2*60-1), 0))
    )
    .withColumn(
        "mean3Mins", F.mean("val1").over(win_physical.rangeBetween(-(3*60-1), 0))
    )
    .show()
)
```

The physical plan reveals using three windows for the above example

```
== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 21
+- *(6) Project [segId#0, cast(time#8 as string) AS time#102, cast(val1#2 as string) AS val1#97, cast(val2#3L as string) AS val2#98, cast(mean1Mins#63 as string) AS mean1Mins#99, cast(mean2Mins#71 as string) AS mean2Mins#100, cast(mean3Mins#80 as string) AS mean3Mins#101]
   +- Window [avg(val1#2) windowspecdefinition(segId#0, _w0#81L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, -179, currentrow$())) AS mean3Mins#80], [segId#0], [_w0#81L ASC NULLS FIRST]
      +- *(5) Sort [segId#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, _w0#81L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- *(5) Project [segId#0, time#8, val1#2, val2#3L, mean1Mins#63, mean2Mins#71, cast(time#8 as bigint) AS _w0#81L]
            +- Window [avg(val2#3L) windowspecdefinition(segId#0, _w0#72L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, -119, currentrow$())) AS mean2Mins#71], [segId#0], [_w0#72L ASC NULLS FIRST]
               +- *(4) Sort [segId#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, _w0#72L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                  +- *(4) Project [segId#0, time#8, val1#2, val2#3L, mean1Mins#63, cast(time#8 as bigint) AS _w0#72L]
                     +- Window [avg(val1#2) windowspecdefinition(segId#0, _w0#64L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, -59, currentrow$())) AS mean1Mins#63], [segId#0], [_w0#64L ASC NULLS FIRST]
                        +- *(3) Sort [segId#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, _w0#64L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                           +- Exchange hashpartitioning(segId#0, 1000)
                              +- *(2) Project [segId#0, time#8, val1#2, val2#3L, cast(time#8 as bigint) AS _w0#64L]
                                 +- *(2) Sort [cast(time#8 as bigint) ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
                                    +- Exchange rangepartitioning(cast(time#8 as bigint) ASC NULLS FIRST, 1000)
                                       +- Exchange hashpartitioning(segId#0, 1000)
                                          +- *(1) Project [segId#0, cast(time#1 as timestamp) AS time#8, val1#2, val2#3L]
                                             +- Scan ExistingRDD[segId#0,time#1,val1#2,val2#3L]
```

My question is:

1. Will spark reuse the same physical partition (i.e., one paritioned and ordered once) for multiple logical windows? Or will it create a separate paritions and sorting for each `rangeBetween` (computationally intensive)?
2. Any suggestion to computationally improve the above logic for custom aggregations over different `rangeBetween` on same partition?

Answer (score 0):

> Will spark reuse the same physical partition (i.e., one paritioned and ordered once) for multiple logical windows? Or will it create a separate paritions and sorting for each rangeBetween (computationally intensive)?

Think so. Only `Exchange` operators could repartition data (that are close to the data source `Scan ExistingRDD`).

> Any suggestion to computationally improve the above logic for custom aggregations over different rangeBetween on same partition?

No idea here. Sorry.